# Segmentation Fault in C when reading a file full of ints

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, readfile

I am simply trying to open a file and read the ints and print the array. However, a segmentation fault shows up. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int size;
   int i;
   FILE* p = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   fscanf(p, "%d", &size);
   int a[size];

   for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      a[i] = fscanf(p,"%d",&a[i]);

   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
      printf("%d", a[i]);
  }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us command line (and arguments) and  the file contents. And Read [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and Check return value of `fopen` and `fscanf`.

Comment: The text file is not shown to me. It could be any, all I know is that it is full of whole numbers

Comment: The size is first read from the file, but when it is too large to reserve on the stack, it becomes one cause of the seg fault.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that when we do not know the size?

Comment: Maybe if there are no spaces between the numbers it tries to read everything as the size and allocate the array? That would definitely seg fault

Comment: If all you need to do is echo all the file's contents then why do you need an array at all?  Just print each number immediately after you read it.

Comment: @user7729282 If you are assuming a large size for the time being, use `malloc` instead of VLA.

Comment: There are white spaces between the numbers

Comment: Also, `fscanf()`'s return value is *not* ordinarily one of the values it scanned -- it is the number of values it successfully scanned.  As such, it is unlikely that assigning that return value to `a[i]` is what you really want to do.

Comment: I have never used malloc. Do I incorporate like this:                                        char *argv[] = (char*)malloc(size);

Comment: E.g `int *a = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));` instead of `int a[size];`.

Comment: I have added that and the segmentation fault still continues

Comment: can you add an example of the file you are reading?

Comment: An exmaple is: 1332 324 7 9 6382 937 849 -12

Comment: But it can be many more ints

Comment: first, Are you giving command arguments? If no command line argument is given Access to `argv[1]` is one cause of a seg fault.

Comment: Yes I am giving command line arguments

Comment: Also `1332`  is not that big.

Comment: The test file is just an example.

Comment: Please check `p` before `fscanf`.  like `if(p == NULL){ perror("fopen"); return -1;}`

Comment: I will add the verification of the file, but it is certain that there is a file named that for my task.

Comment: So far, We can not ascertain anything you say. Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine, however you can add some validation to it to make sure your input is correct.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int size=0;
   int i=0;
   int ret=0;

   // make sure arcv[1] exists:
   if (argc < 2)
   {
       printf("not enough arguments provided");
       return -1;
   }

   FILE* p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   // make sure file exists
   if (p == 0) // or p == NULL
   {
       printf("file does not exists");
       return -1;
   }

   ret = fscanf(p, "%d", &size);
   // make sure the size is a valid number
   if (ret == EOF || ret <= 0 || size <= 0)
   {
       printf("invalid file");
       return -1;
   }
   int a[size];

   for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      fscanf(p,"%d",a+i);
   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      printf("%d", a[i]);
   }

}
```

Comment: You should also validate fscsnf return values. For example size might remain uninitialized when you test it with invalid file here.

Comment: @hyde Thanks for your comment.